# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' in php file

Tags: php, sql

So we want to insert pdf files to a database from a directory.

Here is the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. in D:\dir\dir\dbData.php:662

Code:

dbData.php:

```
public function insFile($filename)
{
    $db = getDB();
    $query = $db->prepare("
                INSERT INTO images(id, imageFile)
                SELECT NEWID(), BulkColumn
                FROM OPENROWSET(BULK :filename, SINGLE_BLOB) as f;

        ");

    $query->bindParam(':filename', $filename, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
    $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    $query->execute();   // THIS IS THE 662ND LINE

    $db = null;
    return null;
}
```

and

home.php

```
<?php
require_once(_DIR_.'/'.'oconfig.php');

foreach (glob("D:/dir/dir/pdf/*.pdf") as $filename) {
    $filename = "D:/dir/dir/pdf/" . basename($filename);     
    $userData=$dbData->insFile($filename);
    echo $userData;
}
?>
```

Comment: I remember running into this recently as I wanted to bulk import a file into a blob column. You cannot pass a parameter into a `OPENROWSET` even if filename resembles a string literal. It needs to be hardcoded in the call.

Comment: thank you very much! it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the `BULK` *filename* string literal in SQL Server's [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) cannot be parameterized. Instead, consider directly concatenating the filename into the call for iterative loop run.

```
public function insFile($filename)
{
    $db = getDB();
    $query = $db->query("
                  INSERT INTO images(id, imageFile)
                  SELECT NEWID(), BulkColumn
                  FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '$filename', SINGLE_BLOB) as f;
             ");

    $db = null;
    return null;
}
```